# Android device with custom ROM - Is it still possible to use this device for testing?

Tags: android, testing, rom

The title says it all. I'm thinking to get a custom ROM, but I want to use my phone for testing android apps. Will there be any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you may still develop apps and test them in your phone. You may get some errors which could be only happening due to your custom ROM, idk maybe the camera not functioning right,etc,etc, etc, but for the most of it, no, it shouldn't be a problem